# Issue with selecting an item from an AJAX AutoComplete list - not returning the required value(s)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sql-server-2008, autocomplete, webforms

I am having an issue with what I believe is the AJAX AutoComplete extender for an ASP.NET page.

Basically I have a form where a user enters a variety of info.  It’s the FOD entry form.  One of the input boxes on this FOD entry form is to select an organization - this has a corresponding hyperlink which upon clicking takes them to the search form to select an organization.

For this search form I am using UpdatePanels and AutoExtenders.  So, a user can begin typing in either an org code or an org name and the AJAX AutoExtender will display a dropdown as they type which displays the possible org codes and names.
If they hit “Enter” with either a partial entry or full entry of the org they want, a hyperlink will display with the org code, name, and address for each of the possibles.  They can then click the link for the org they want and it will return to the FOD entry form with the organization box populated with the data they selected from the org search form.

However, the problem is if they don’t hit “Enter” but rather select a name from the drop down list by using the mouse, that hyperlink containing the info they need to populate the FOD form will not show.  I haven’t been able to figure this out thus far and am wondering if it’s something I’m doing in the AJAX controls.  Any help would me most appreciated!

Thanks!

**Here is the code for just the part under discussion (OrganizationSearch.aspx):**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="OrganizationName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    OnTextChanged="GetCompleteList" Width="420px" />
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender 
                    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
                    TargetControlID="OrganizationName" 
                    runat="server"
                    ServiceMethod="getNames"
                    CompletionInterval="500"
                    minimumprefixLength="1"
                    completionsetcount="5"
                    />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView 
                id="GridView1" 
                runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="700px"
                >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select the organization from the list below:">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#"<a href='javascript:setParentName(" + Eval("OrganizationID").ToString() + ",&#039;" + Eval("Organization").ToString() + "&#039;);'>" + Eval("Organization").ToString() + "</a>"%>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OrganizationName" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>                            
                            </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="primarylight" style="MIN-HEIGHT: 0.042in">
            <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1pt; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1pt; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-TOP: 1px">
                <h4 align="center" style="FONT-WEIGHT: normal">If you cannot find a particular organization, please contact the help desk via phone (000) 000-0000 or visit the website at: 
                     <a target="_blank" href="helpdeskwebsite" 
                        xd:disableediting="yes"><font size="2">Organizational Help Desk</font></a>&nbsp;The following information is required: Org Code, name, address, and phone number of the organization</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="primarylight" style="MIN-HEIGHT: 0.042in">
            <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1pt; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1pt; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-TOP: 1px" align="center">

            </td>
        </tr>
```

**Here is the code for the full page:**

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OrganizationSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="PMT30.Layouts.PMT30.OrganizationSearch" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.50508.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

 <style type="text/css">

TABLE {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none
}
TABLE {
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 10pt
}
TABLE {
    BEHAVIOR: url (#default#urn::tables/NDTable)
}
.primaryVeryDark {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #1e3c7b; COLOR: #ebf0f9
}
TABLE.xdFormLayout TD {
    BEHAVIOR: url(#default#LayoutText)
}
TABLE.xdLayout TD {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none
}
TD {
    BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #517dbf; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #517dbf; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #517dbf; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #517dbf
}
.primaryLight {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ebf0f9; COLOR: black
}
H4 {
    MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; COLOR: #1e3c7b
}
.xdRepeating {
    DISPLAY: inline-block; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#RepeatingItemUI) url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdSection {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #ffffff 1pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: #ffffff 1pt solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; MARGIN: 6px 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; BORDER-TOP: #ffffff 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #ffffff 1pt solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px
}
.xdTextBox {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BORDER-LEFT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: window; MARGIN: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; DISPLAY: inline-block; WORD-WRAP: normal; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; COLOR: windowtext; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdAspTextBox {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BORDER-LEFT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: window; MARGIN: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; DISPLAY: inline-block; WORD-WRAP: normal; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; COLOR: windowtext; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdBehavior_Select {
    BEHAVIOR: url(#default#SelectHelper) url(#default#DataBindingUI/Select)
}
.xdComboBox {
    MARGIN: 1px
}
SELECT {
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 10pt
}
.xdXButton {
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdBehavior_Boolean {
    BEHAVIOR: url(#default#BooleanHelper) url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdDTPicker {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: window; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; MARGIN: 1px 1px 2px; DISPLAY: inline; COLOR: windowtext; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdDTText {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; HEIGHT: 100%; OVERFLOW: hidden; MARGIN-RIGHT: 22px; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
.xdBehavior_FormattingNoBUI {
    BEHAVIOR: url(#default#Formatting)
}
.xdDTButton {
    WIDTH: 20px; HEIGHT: 18px; MARGIN-LEFT: -21px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#DTPicker)
}
.xdRichTextBox {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BORDER-LEFT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; OVERFLOW-X: hidden; BACKGROUND-COLOR: window; FONT-STYLE: normal; MARGIN: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; DISPLAY: inline-block; WORD-WRAP: break-word; COLOR: windowtext; VERTICAL-ALIGN: baseline; BORDER-TOP: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; BORDER-RIGHT: #dcdcdc 1pt solid; TEXT-DECORATION: none; PADDING-TOP: 1px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdBehavior_Formatting {
    BEHAVIOR: url(#default#Formatting) url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
TABLE.msoUcTable TD {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: 1pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1pt solid; BORDER-TOP: 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 1pt solid
}
.xdRepeatingTable {
    BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#urn::tables/NDTable) url(#default#RepeatingItemUI) url(#default#DataBindingUI)
}
.xdTableHeader {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ebf0f9; COLOR: black
}
.xdRepeatingTable TD {
    VERTICAL-ALIGN: top
}
     .style1
     {
         color: #FF0000;
     }
     .style2
     {
         width: 183px;
     }
     .style3
     {
         width: 81px;
     }
     .style4
     {
         width: 15px;
     }
     .style5
     {
         width: 182px;
     }
 </style>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Organization Selection</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var Prefix = "FODForm_TabContainer1_TabPanelRI_RI_";
        var PrefixPI = "FODForm_TabContainer1_TabPanelPI_PI_";
        var PrefixPT = "FODForm_TabContainer1_TabPanelPT_PT_";
        var PrefixFI = "FODForm_TabContainer1_TabPanelFI_FI_";
        var PrefixIC = "FODForm_TabContainer1_TabPanelIC_IC_";
        var PrefixPSI = "FODForm_TabContainer1_TabPanelPSI_PSI_";

        function setParentName(FOD, fName) {

            var organization = opener.document.getElementById(Prefix + "txtOrganization");
            var organizationid = opener.document.getElementById(Prefix + "txtOrganizationID");
            if (organization) {
                organization.value = fName;
                organizationid.value = FOD;
                //opener.document.getElementById(Prefix + "txtOrganization").value = fName;
                //opener.document.getElementById(Prefix + "txtOrganizationID").value = FOD;

            }
            else {
                organization = opener.document.getElementById("CtrInfoForm_txtOrganization");
                organizationid = opener.document.getElementById("CtrInfoForm_txtOrganizationID");
                organization.value = fName;
                organizationid.value = FOD;
            }
            self.close();

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">

        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>    
<div style="width: 767px" >
    <table table border="1" class="xdFormLayout xdLayout" 
    style="BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; WIDTH: 765px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none" 
    tabindex="-1">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="WIDTH: 754px" />
    </colgroup>

         <tr class="primaryVeryDark" style="MIN-HEIGHT: 27px">
            <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1pt solid; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1pt solid">
                <div align="center">
                    <font size="4">Search/Select Organization</font></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="primarylight" style="MIN-HEIGHT: 0.042in">
            <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 5pt solid; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BORDER-LEFT: #517dbf 1pt solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-TOP: #517dbf 1pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #517dbf 1pt solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px">

               <div align="center">
                    <table border="1" bordercolor="buttontext" class="xdLayout" 
                        style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; WIDTH: 640px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; WORD-WRAP: break-word; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; " 
                        tabindex="-1">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col style="WIDTH: 100px" />
                            <col style="WIDTH: 250px" />
                        </colgroup>
                        <tbody valign="top">            
                            <tr style="MIN-HEIGHT: 27px">
                                <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; PADDING-TOP: 1px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrganization" runat="server" Text="Enter name to search:" Font-Bold="True" 
                                        Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1E3C7B" Width="170px"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="OrganizationName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    OnTextChanged="GetCompleteList" Width="420px" />
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender 
                    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
                    TargetControlID="OrganizationName" 
                    runat="server"
                    ServiceMethod="getNames"
                    CompletionInterval="500"
                    minimumprefixLength="1"
                    completionsetcount="5"
                    />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView 
                id="GridView1" 
                runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="700px"
                >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select the organization from the list below:">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#"<a href='javascript:setParentName(" + Eval("OrganizationID").ToString() + ",&#039;" + Eval("Organization").ToString() + "&#039;);'>" + Eval("Organization").ToString() + "</a>"%>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OrganizationName" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>                            
                            </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="primarylight" style="MIN-HEIGHT: 0.042in">
            <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1pt; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1pt; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-TOP: 1px">
                <h4 align="center" style="FONT-WEIGHT: normal">If you cannot find a particular organization, please contact the help desk via phone (000) 000-0000 or visit the website at: 
                     <a target="_blank" href="helpdeskwebsite" 
                        xd:disableediting="yes"><font size="2">Organizational Help Desk</font></a>&nbsp;The following information is required: Org Code, name, address, and phone number of the organization</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="primarylight" style="MIN-HEIGHT: 0.042in">
            <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1pt; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1pt; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1pt; PADDING-TOP: 1px" align="center">

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

</div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is the code that retrieves the data (OrganizationSearch.aspx.cs):**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IDE_Utility.DBConnection;

namespace ORG40.Layouts.ORG40
{
    public partial class OrganizationSearch : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GetCompleteList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();

            SqlParameter sqlParamComp = new SqlParameter();
            sqlParamComp.ParameterName = "@oName";
            sqlParamComp.DbType = DbType.String;
            sqlParamComp.Value = "%" + OrganizationName.Text + "%";

            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@orgCode", DBNull.Value),                
                sqlParamComp
            };

            DS = DBConnection.GetDataSet("getL_Organization", CommandType.StoredProcedure, sqlParams);
            GridView1.DataSource = DS;
            GridView1.DataBind();



        }
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string[] getNames(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            SqlParameter sqlParamComp = new SqlParameter();
            sqlParamComp.ParameterName = "@oName";
            sqlParamComp.DbType = DbType.String;
            sqlParamComp.Value = "%" + prefixText + "%";

            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@orgCode", DBNull.Value),                
                sqlParamComp
            };

            DS = DBConnection.GetDataSet("getL_Organization", CommandType.StoredProcedure, sqlParams);


            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] {"OrgCode", "Name"});
            DataRow[] Dr = new DataRow[Dt.Rows.Count];
            Dt.Rows.CopyTo(Dr, 0);
            return Array.ConvertAll(Dr, new Converter<DataRow, String>(DataRowToString));

        }

        public static string DataRowToString(DataRow pDr)
        {
            return (Convert.ToString(pDr["OrgCode"]) + ": " + Convert.ToString(pDr["Name"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, sorry for the very long and inaccurate post.  This issue was in my stored procedure which code is not posted.  Was improperly factoring in semicolon in the parameters.